# iPad console warning message: "Received a GSEvent that is not designated....."

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, warnings

I have written a simple multiple choice quiz app. Looking at the console on the iPad (error does not occur on the simulator) I get the waning 
"Received a GSEvent that is not designated as being routed to frontmost (type X), forwarding 
to the System App" where X is 1, 2 or 6.

Anyone got any ideas what this warning means?

There is a lot of code involved but I can post bits depending on what could be important. The app is basically a few screen transitions involving a navigation stack, and some buttons that play different sounds depending on right/wrong answers. I can't find what causes the warning - it doesn't seem to correspond to any user interaction.

I realise this is all a bit vague, but if anyone can point me into the general direction.....

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore this noise. GSEvent is a private CoreFoundation class, you should probably not worry about what it does. There are some inconsistencies in iOS (if you turn off verbose boot in the kernel, that will even show *errors* during booting time), which can 'safely' be ignored - at most file a bug report to Apple, but really, don't bother.

Comment: Seems strange that this warning fires only for one version of my quiz. A second with almost identical code never triggers it. But I will take your advice and ignore it. Thanks